# Не получается включить Django в Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1706]
```

(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

(venv) C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Test1>djnago-admin startproject Test1
"djnago-admin" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

(venv) C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Test1>pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\test1\venv\lib\site-packages (4.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\test1\venv\lib\site-packages (from django) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.5.2 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\test1\venv\lib\site-packages (from django) (3.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\test1\venv\lib\site-packages (from django) (2022.5)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Test1\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(venv) C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Test1>

[image: Скрин Pycharm]
[image: Скрин пакетов]

Comment: Странно у Вас как-то, Вы сначала пытаетесь использовать `django-admin` а потом устанавливаете `Django`

Comment: @Namerek это я показывал,что джанго установлен )